# Heatmap in V3 without Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

The new FusionTablesLayer in Google Maps API version 3 has an option to display as a heatmap instead of points. [Here's the example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/beaches_heatmap.html). Is there a way to get the heat map display without using Fusion Tables (but still using the Google Maps API)? I already have my data in my own PostgreSQL/Postgis database. Having Google do the heatmap a preferred alternative to implementing my own tile server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heatmap Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps) has officially been added to the Google Maps API, no Fusion Table needed.

Comment: Good call. The new functionality finally brings client side heatmap into the API. There may be situations that browser rendering doesn't make sense, but it works for my situation.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a look at gHeat here which might work for you.

http://code.google.com/p/gheat/

Hope it helps

Matt

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have found so far is [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/). It's a nice browser side solution that works pretty well and is surprisingly efficient. The one downside (and it's a big one) is that it uses HTML canvas,so doesn't work on IE versions before version 9.

Comment: You could make it work for IE versions before version 9 with flashcanvas :)

Comment: That's great Patrick! Have you tested heatmap.js with flashcanvas? I'll test it when I get a chance.

Comment: I tried to integrate heatmap.js with flashcanvas and couldn't get it to work in IE 8. Would love to see an example of heatmap.js and flashcanvas working together or if you have tips on how to get them to work together, I would give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'll give it a try after exam time (late feb) and let you know about my results

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try an external service or library, like [Heat Map API](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/density-mapping-in-google-maps-with-heatmapapi/). Apart from Fusion Tables Google does not offer a heat mapping service that can be rendered on the Maps API.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case, at least currently. It wouldn't surprise me if they eventually enable the same sort of thing for KML based overlays, seeing that KML and fusion tables both have the opportunity to be processed and rendered on the server side. Some day, I suppose.